# DocuSign consent is NOT required to log in when log in as another user in your application

Tags: docusignapi

My web application would like to create one DocuSign account per user. Each user can send out documents for signing on behalf of themselves. I'm using Authorization Code Grant flow.

I've created two DocuSign accounts for two users in my application. 
User A logged in and was about to send documents. He's been redirected to this URI: 
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=767b1747-***-6b1f3bd4bc82&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1360/Callback.aspx; 
The page would be be opened in the same browser, on the same tab as my application page. 
Once user A logged in with his own DocuSign account and gave consent. It redirected back to my application. Documents have been sent out successfully.

Then User A logged out from my application, User B logged in. When user B was sending out documents, he would be redirected to https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=767b1747-***-6b1f3bd4bc82&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1360/Callback.aspx; too.
However, User B was not asked to logged in with his own account. It showed the consent page straightaway. Eventaully all the documents sent out on behalf of User A, which was not what I wanted.

Anybody know why? I've been stuck on this issue for days... Please can you help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If the browser has an active DocuSign session, the OAuth workflow will take that for authentication. If you would like to disable this 'silent authentication', add `&prompt=login` to your auth URL to force login every time.

Comment: OMG!!! It works like a magic! Thank you so much Drew! You're a star!